# htop Memory usage vs bar depicted

Tags: ram, memory-usage, htop

Attached is a screenshot from `htop` command. I am wondering why the Mem bar is like 50% full when only 4.1GB out of 126GB is used. Are the Mem bar and the 4.1GB figures representing something different?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the htop faq: http://hisham.hm/htop/index.php?page=faq

> **The memory meter in htop says a low number, such as 9%, when top shows something like 90%! (Or: the MEM% number is low, but the bar looks almost full. What's going on?)**
>
> The number showed by the memory meter is the total memory used by
> processes. The additional available memory is used by the Linux kernel
> for buffering and disk cache, so in total almost the entire memory is
> in use by the kernel. I believe the number displayed by htop is a more
> meaningful metric of resources used: the number corresponds to the
> green bars; the blue and brown bars correspond to buffers and cache,
> respectively (as explained in the Help screen accessible through the
> F1 key). Numeric data about these is also available when configuring
> the memory meter to display as text (in the Setup screen, F2).